# @MastersThesis{} entry results in "MA thesis" output instead of "Master's thesis" with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I use biber and biblatex for my citations. Strangely, if I use the @MastersThesis{} entry, it doesn't output

> [96] Firstname Lastname. “Title goes here”. Master’s
>   thesis. University of the South Pole, YEAR.

which it should according to the biblatex manual but

> [96] Firstname Lastname. “Title goes here”. MA
>   thesis. University of the South Pole, YEAR.

In my latex file, I use the following configuration

```
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    citestyle=nature,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
```

Removing the citestyle and natbib options doesn't help.
I can of course change it to "Master's thesis" using the *type* argument in each one of the entries. But that's annoying and I just want the default.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a good and specific question, but it’d be even better if you provided a full, compilable example like, for example, I did in my answer. For more tips on how to do that (in your next question `;)`), see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that.

Comment: You get the longer term with the option  `abbreviate=false` -- this can affect other terms too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, Ulrike. That simple option solved my problem!

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for the info. You're right. But I was just too lazy to do that ;)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, could you post this an answer?

Comment: @doncherry I did it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When two variants exists for a term, then you get the longer term with the option `abbreviate=false` -- this affects naturally all other terms too.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the relevant bibliography string (`mathesis`) as described in lockstep’s answer to [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    citestyle=nature,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} % That’s a dummy database that comes with biblatex

%%%% The important part:
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  mathesis = {Master's thesis},
}
%%%%

\begin{document}
\nocite{loh}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This could solve my problem, but my preferred solution is the option `abbreviate=false` given by Ulrike Fischer. In that case, I can just use the defaults for the entries.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The "important part" fixed my problem nicely.